# Можно ли разослать на разные адресата разные письма из одного объекта? PHP | PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Проблема в дублировании однотипного кода, так еще и большого размера.
Я использую PHPMailer для рассылки почты. В одном скрипте нужно отправить два письма: одно пользователю, другое в поддержку. Естественно адресаты и содержание разные.
Проблема в том, что код отправки одного сообщения требует около 10 строк без наличия проверок... Дважды дублировать такой объем для отправки другого письма в поддержку - бред, имхо.

Есть ли способ отправить два письма на разные адресаты, НО И с разным содержанием? (просто на разные адресаты можно, знаю. А вот с разным содержанием - не знаю). Или придется вот так код дублировать?

Comment: функцию написать не пробовали? Говорят помогает от дублирования кода

Comment: @ArchDemon что-то я затупил сильно, да?